# Empty HTML tag in an editable div disappears when backspace is pressed on Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, contenteditable

I'm using Firefox and I have this HTML code:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
   This is an empty tag : <b></b> and this is this is <b>not</b>
</div>
```

When I try to delete a character by pressing the "SUPPR" or "BACKSPACE" key, it removes the `<b></b>` for no reason.

It works on Chrome.

Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/t5jgb04y/
And then try to delete a character.

Answer (score 6):

I think that in this case Firefox is smarter than Chrome, because you cannot do anything with this `<b></b>` tag inside your `<div contenteditable>`. Try to insert content in the `<b>` tag when navigating with the keyboard arrows or by mouse - **you can't**. So basically Firefox is just removing this kind of tags on any change, because they are simply not usable.

Now change `<b></b>` to `<b> </b>` or even `<b>&nbsp;</b>` to have an empty space between those `<b>` tags - Firefox won't auto-remote the `<b>` tag on change and you are now able to navigate and edit its content.

Here is your sample:

```css
b {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  This is an empty tag : <b></b> and this is <b>not</b>
</div>
```

And here is my sample with empty space character between the tags `<b>&nbsp;</b>`:

```css
b {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  This is an empty tag : <b>&nbsp;</b> and this is this is <b>not</b>
</div>
```

And another sample just with empty space between the tags `<b> </b>` - in this case you can only navigate between the `<b></b>` with the keyboard arrows:

```css
b {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  This is an empty tag : <b> </b> and this is this is <b>not</b>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes but even if the tag is empty, it shouldn't be removed. In my example, I agree the `<b></b>` is useless. But replace that by `<i class"icon"></i>` and you seel Firefox stil removes it even if it shoud not.

Comment: Then put an empty space between those tags `<i class="icon"> </i>` and Firefox won't remove it

Comment: I would if I could but that's not possible in my case. We are rendering client's website. I don't want to change the HTML but I'm looking for a way to workaround which I consider is a bug

Answer (score 1):

Adding the `contenteditable="false"` attribute to the empty `<b>` tag seems to work:

```css
b {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  This is an empty tag: <b contenteditable="false"></b> and this is <b>not</b>.
</div>
```

Note that, as a side effect, the `contenteditable="false"` attribute also prevents the user from adding any content inside the empty element.  In your actual use case, where you're apparently styling the empty element to look like a graphical icon, this is probably fine and even desirable, but it could potentially be a problem in other cases.

---

Also, it seems that having non-editable inline elements inside an editable section can lead to inconsistent (and sometimes arguably buggy) behavior between different browsers in some edge cases.  In particular, I have so far tested the snippet above on Firefox 69 and Chrome 76, and have observed the following quirks:

- Neither Firefox nor Chrome allows the user to position the caret inside the non-editable empty element using the mouse.
- On Firefox, using the arrow keys to try to move the caret into the non-editable element causes it to jump from one side of the element to the other.  (For things like icons, this is presumably what you want.)  Chrome *does* allow moving the caret inside the element using the arrow keys, but trying to type any text there will pop the caret out and cause the text to appear to the right of the element.
- Neither Firefox nor Chrome allows the non-editable empty element to be deleted by placing the caret to the right of it and pressing backspace.  However, selecting the element (either with the mouse, or by using shift + arrow keys) allows it to be deleted with backspace, cut with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, or just typed over and replaced with normal text.
- Pressing backspace while the caret is to the right of the non-editable empty element *and then typing some text* triggers what seems to be a bug in Chrome, causing the element to be duplicated!  The duplicate element thus generated loses the `contenteditable="false"` attribute, and is thus normally editable.  For some reason, it also gets wrapped in a `<span>` that has the original element's `background-color` as an inline style.  Firefox doesn't seem to suffer from this bug.
- Adding some content (even just a space) inside the non-editable element changes the behavior on Chrome: pressing backspace while the caret is to the right of the element now deletes it, and thus does not trigger the bug described above.  On Firefox, the behavior is unchanged.

All in all, given these observations, I would suggest the following best practices:

1. Have some content inside the element, even if it's just an invisible [Unicode zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) (`&#x200B;`) or a [word joiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_joiner) (`&#x2060;`).  (Note that this alone will prevent the element from disappearing when other content is edited on Firefox, even without `contenteditable="false"`.)
2. If you don't want the user to be able to type additional content inside the element (which you probably don't, for an icon), also add the `contenteditable="false"` attribute to it.
3. If you want the user to be able to delete the icon element using backspace on Firefox, you may need to write your own `keydown` event handler that checks if the caret is to the right of the icon and, if so, adjusts the selection to cover the whole icon, e.g. like this:

```js
for (const editable of document.querySelectorAll('[contenteditable=true]')) {
  editable.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
    // only trigger on plain backspace presses
    if (event.key !== 'Backspace') return;
    if (event.isComposing || event.altKey || event.metaKey || event.ctrlKey || event.shiftKey ) return;

    // don't trigger if the selection is extended
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    if (!selection.isCollapsed) return;

    // only trigger if the caret is inside or just after a non-editable element
    // this is a bit tricky: basically, we climb down the DOM tree until we find
    // a previous sibling node, and then up again, while making sure we don't
    // climb out of the editable element; if we encounter any element with
    // contenteditable=false, we stop climbing there 
    let node = selection.focusNode, offset = selection.focusOffset;
    if (offset > 0) {
      // if the caret is in the middle of a text node, we can safely stop
      if (!node.hasChildNodes()) return;
      // else the caret is between two child nodes, and we need to start
      // the climb up from the earlier of the two
      node = node.childNodes[offset - 1];
    } else {
      // if the caret is at the beginning of a node with no previous sibling,
      // climb down until we find such a sibling (or find a non-editable parent
      // or climb out of the editable element entirely)
      while (node && node !== editable && !node.previousSibling && node.contentEditable !== 'false') {
        node = node.parentNode;
      }
      // if the caret was at the very beginning of the editable element, stop
      if (!node || node === editable) return;
      // otherwise, if the caret wasn't inside a non-editable node, check if
      // it might be immediately after one
      if (node.contentEditable !== 'false') node = node.previousSibling;
    }
    // at this point, if we're still inside the editable section and haven't
    // found a non-editable child node yet, we need to start climbing back up
    // and look at all the nodes that end just before the caret to see if any
    // of them might be non-editable
    while (node && node.contentEditable !== 'false') {
      node = node.lastChild;
    }
    if (!node) return;

    // if we got here, we've found a non-editable node around or just before
    // the caret; now select it all so that it will get deleted!
    const range = document.createRange()
    range.selectNode(node);
    selection.addRange(range);
  } );
}
```

```css
b {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  This is an empty <i>tag: <b contenteditable="false">&#x200B;</b> but</i> this is <b>not</b>.
</div>
```

(Yes, that's a lot of JS code for what *seems* like a simple task: find out if the cursor is just after an element with `contenteditable="false"` and if so, select it.  One source of complication is that the element with `contenteditable="false"` might be nested inside one or more other elements; another is that the caret position reported by `getSelection()` could *also* be nested inside one or more elements that follow the non-editable one.  And in some rare cases, even on Firefox, it's actually possible for the caret to end up *inside* the supposedly non-editable element, e.g. if you delete everything else after it.  I've at least tried to include plenty of comments explaining what the code does.)

Comment: Thanks but I would like to not modify the HTML and indeed I'm afraid of side effect by adding contenteditable=false. I start to believe this is more a bug on Firefox than a expected behavior

Comment: You could always set `element.contentEditable = true` for the empty elements in JS. And yes, I do agree that this should be considered a bug, or at least a problematic feature, in Firefox. (It's not a trivial bug, however, since often auto-removing empty inline elements while editing is desirable — otherwise it would be all too easy to end up with an ever-increasing number of invisible empty elements as they get added and never removed. Possibly there should be some logic like "if the element has padding / borders / something else that makes it visible even when empty, don't remove it.")

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up on this if it helps someone, as I believed it's a bug, I created an issue on Bugzilla.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1583209

You can follow the status directly on that page